# AngularJs controller is called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Each of my controller is executed twice when i click the controller link. In my view i have not defined a ng-controller. Here is my app.js where the routes are defined:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [ 'ngRoute', 'routeStyles', 'angular-growl' ]);    

// Routes
$routeProvider
    // PAGES
    .when('/about/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController',
        css:'views/css/aboutCustomer.css'
    })
});

app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
   // some post request here
   ...
   $rootScope.$apply(); // trigger digest loop
)};
```

The template contains only html but my controller is executed twice.

```
app.controller('aboutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log('why is executed twice??');
}]);
```

Menu link:

```
<li><a href="#/about/">About</a></li>
```

Comment: Make sure there is no `ng-controller='aboutController'` in html.

Comment: can you please create a plunker or fiddle ?

Comment: Did you check both your "index" file and the template file for an extra ng-controller expression?

Comment: Why are you running a $rootScope.$apply in the run phase of your main app?

Comment: The problem was the following forgotten div *<div ng-view></div>* in index.